# Merge with condition in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hello everyone I would need help in order to merge informations between two dataframe with conditions.

Here are the 2 df:

**df1**

```
   Groups Species sub_group Name
1      G1       B        s1   KO
2      G1       B        s1   KO
3      G1       B        s1   KO
4      G1       B        s1   AL
5      G1       B        s1   AL
6      G1       B        s1   AL
7      G2       B        s1   KO
8      G2       B        s1   KO
9      G3       A        s2  ZIP
10     G3       A        s2  ZIP
11     G3       A        s3  ZIP
12     G4       C        s4  LOP
13     G4       C        s4  AKA
```

**df2**

```
 Group Species sub_group Value
1    G1       B        s1 BLOC1
2    G3       A        s2 BLOC2
3    G4       C        s4 BLOC3
```

and the idea is that I would like to add a `df1$New_col` with the `df2$Value` `"BlocN"` value when  cols `Group`, `Species`, `sub_group` are the same `AND` also when there is duplicated `df1$Name` within that `groupby c(Group, Species,sub_group)`.

If we follow that rules I should get then :

```
   Groups Species sub_group Name New_Col
1      G1       B        s1   KO   BLOC1
2      G1       B        s1   KO   BLOC1
3      G1       B        s1   KO   BLOC1
4      G1       B        s1   AL   BLOC1
5      G1       B        s1   AL   BLOC1
6      G1       B        s1   AL   BLOC1
7      G2       B        s1   KO        
8      G2       B        s1   KO        
9      G3       A        s2  ZIP   BLOC2
10     G3       A        s2  ZIP   BLOC2
11     G3       A        s3  ZIP        
12     G4       C        s4  LOP        
13     G4       C        s4  AKA
```

for instance in `G4,C,s4` there is no duplicate values within the `df1$Name`

Does someone have an idea please, thank you very mocy for your help and time.

Here are the dput data

**df1**

```
structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"), class = "factor"), 
    Species = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    sub_group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"), class = "factor"), 
    Name = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("AKA", "AL", "KO", "LOP", "ZIP"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

**df2**

```
structure(list(Group = structure(1:3, .Label = c("G1", "G3", 
"G4"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), sub_group = structure(1:3, .Label = c("s1", 
"s2", "s4"), class = "factor"), Value = structure(1:3, .Label = c("BLOC1", 
"BLOC2", "BLOC3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: What should be the output if there's a 14th row as G4, C, s4, AKA? As there will now be two values in grp, one with duplicates and another without duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with join and then we `replace` the column created to `NA` where the number of rows per group are 1

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("Groups" = "Group", "Species", "sub_group")) %>% 
    group_by(Groups, Species, sub_group, Name) %>%
    mutate(New_Col = replace(Value, n() == 1, NA_character_), Value = NULL) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 13 x 5
#   Groups Species sub_group Name  New_Col
#   <fct>  <fct>   <fct>     <fct> <fct>  
# 1 G1     B       s1        KO    BLOC1  
# 2 G1     B       s1        KO    BLOC1  
# 3 G1     B       s1        KO    BLOC1  
# 4 G1     B       s1        AL    BLOC1  
# 5 G1     B       s1        AL    BLOC1  
# 6 G1     B       s1        AL    BLOC1  
# 7 G2     B       s1        KO    <NA>   
# 8 G2     B       s1        KO    <NA>   
# 9 G3     A       s2        ZIP   BLOC2  
#10 G3     A       s2        ZIP   BLOC2  
#11 G3     A       s3        ZIP   <NA>   
#12 G4     C       s4        LOP   <NA>   
#13 G4     C       s4        AKA   <NA>
```